# Enclosured php element in p-tag is ouside p, how is this possible?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields in wordpress and having this line of code:

```
<p class="small"><?php the_field('somefield', 'options'); ?></p>
```

And it is printed like this in the browser:

```
<p class="small></p>
<p>the content of somefield</p>
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Probably because of `wpautop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because you are using paragraph inside and paragraph you can fix it by using the fix below , if you are inserting the `<p>` inside this field , please use `span` or something else it will cause this problem if you use `<p>`:

```
<?php 
   $myfield = the_field('somefield', 'options');
   echo strip_tags($myfield, '<p></p>');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Arsh gave a good answer.

Let me explain the inner-workings of it in WordPress Methodology.

Most function which starts with `the_{function_name}` most of the time has a function `get_the_{function_name}`.

Since `the_{function_name}` is a function to output the field and not threat it has data unlike `get_the_{function_name}`.

Here is a simple example with `the_ID()`

```
function the_ID() {
    echo get_the_ID();
}
```

And here is an example with `get_the_ID()`

```
function get_the_ID() {
    $post = get_post();
    return ! empty( $post ) ? $post->ID : false;
}
```

Understanding those pattern better your understanding of WordPress conventions and its inner workings.

You can always check official documentation to understand WordPress functions.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/

or check in with plugin developers docs.